# How can I check that a particular constant exists in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Say I have the following:

```
person(james).
person(pete).

father(james, pete).
```

Is there a way to validate that both the arguments to `father` have been defined i.e to stop a typo such as `father(jmes, pete)`.

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy way of checking these kinds of errors using Prolog: You can call rules at initialization time, i.e. one that checks that your fathers relations is properly defined. This can be useful to catch those typo errors.

```
:- use_module(library(error)).

check_fathers :-
    % Take an element of the father relation
    (father(P, _); father(_, P)),
    % Proceed, if P is not a person
    \+ person(P),
    % Throw an error
    syntax_error(father_is_no_person(P)).

 check_fathers.
 :- check_fathers.

 person(james).
 person(pete).

 father(jame, pete). % TYPO! jame instead of james
```

Then, the program will produce the following output:

```
ERROR: Syntax error: father_is_no_person(jame)
Warning: <filename>:<line>:
Warning:    Goal (directive) failed: user:check_fathers
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are wrong in this sense:

`father(james, pete).`  is a *fact*. It is something that you tell the Prolog processor is uneniably true (similar to a row in a table in a relational database).

So is `father(jmes, pete).`. Another fact. You are stating that this is so.

There is nothing to check, really.

On the other hand, if `father(jmes, pete)` appears in a a goal position, the Prolog processor will say "no, I have no indiciation that this is true":

```
father(james, pete). % that's a fat fact!
```

```
?- father(jmes, pete).  % that's a query
false.                  % and the answer is "no, there is no evidence of that"
```

What you you would like to have is to have something like [Java `enum` types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html): have the compiler make sure that a keyword comes indeed from a selected set of allowed keywords.

Prolog has has only basic typing, so this cannot be done directly.

But you could do this:

```
% if X is an unbound variable or a member of the indicated list,
% we are good

allowed_father(X) :- 
   (var(X);memberchk(X,[james,vader])),!.  

% otherwise, we don't just fail, we actually throw an exception

allowed_father(X) :- 
   throw(error(unknown_father(X))).

% ---

% if X is an unbound variable or a member of the indicated list,
% we are good

allowed_son(X) :- 
   (var(X);memberchk(X,[pete,luke])),!.

% otherwise, we don't just fail, we actually throw an exception

allowed_father(X) :- 
   throw(error(unknown_son(X))).
```

and then you can call the above predicates whenever you need to perform a check:

```
query_anout(Father) :- 
   allowed_father(Father),
   ...
```

But it's rather awkward. Plus the thrown exception is not ISO-standard and the resulting error message may be confusing (I always rage against ISO standard exceptions which are doubleplusungood awkward)